# Is there a way to create patterns similar to the Waveform Drawing display shown in Fairlight CMI?

Tags: software-recommendation, style-identification, music

I have leaned that  Fairlight Computer Musical Instrument (CMI) is a kind of commercially available digital sampler in 80s. I don't know much about music and programming related knowledge. I just noticed that the Fairlight CMI's screen can display beautiful waveform graphics based on brush strokes, like this (I found the pictures on the internet):

[image]

[image]

I wonder if there is a term to describe this aesthetic style? This waveform also reminds me of the album cover for the band Joy Division's 'Unknown Pleasures'. What software and methods can I use to replicate this visual effect?
What I'm thinking is that I can input an audio clip and generate a waveform drawing that displays the audio in this visual style.

Comment: Not that you need this info to be able to draw one for yourself, but this is an early method of rendering a Fast Fourier Transform [FFT]. They get far more complex these days. Overall it represents frequency over time. Basically, each 'squiggly line' is sound frequency against volume [higher = louder], bass to the left, treble to the right. Each line behind is a pace back in time.

Comment: Even as long ago as 15 years or so, you could compute these in realtime - it was a common theme for iTunes visualiser plugins at the time.

Comment: yes! I found the way! We can use a sound visualization software called TouchDesigner to do this and I found the tutorial on Youtube. (Using Joy Division and TouchDesigner as keywords)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the "Page D" of Fairlight CMI music computer in 1980's. It visualized how the used waveform evolved during the time. One could use it to see what he had in the waveform memory. The view was  pleasant and artistically attractive in case one line was set to show one or few full cycles of the waveform and the adjacent cycles didn't differ too much. Your example is not such case, it looks more chaotic.

No onscreen editing was possible in page D, but the view obviously was useful for users who understood well how the machine worked. Read more from this http://www.muzines.co.uk/articles/the-fairlight-explained/7992

You can draw a lookalike in Ilustrator or Inkscape (or in any other well equipped vector drawing program)quite easily.

See the next image:

[image]

In the left I drew a random waveform to the bottom and a straight line on the top. The intermediate versions are made by applying Object > Blend in Illustrator.

In the result is colored to green and a black background is inserted to imitate old monochrome cathode ray tube computer screens. They were often green.

The drawn curve was made with the Pencil tool. To make it look more organic I applied the Wrinkle tool to get some vertical noise-like twists. The intermediate versions show how the waveform evolve from the loud start to silence.

I'm afraid this wouln't sound anything very interesting if it could be played because it evolves only by reducing the volume i.e. Y-scale towards the silence. Realistic instrument sounds should have also some basic form evolution. Musically it means evolution in harmonic content. In fake drawing terms it means that some drawn intermediate forms in the blend are also needed.

Of course you can draw manually every waveform in the set. To get it right get at first a regular set of straight lines  with blending. Use it as your start and endpoint markers. Lock it and draw each waveform one by one on the lines. Or draw only few and create the rest by blending. To make it look as a physically possible sound file every curve should start from the same elevation where the previous one ended and preferably also to point to the same tangential direction.

Fairlight CMI became obsolete already about 20 years ago when no special hardware was any more needed.  Everything became possible to be done by running generally available sound editing and music arranging software in an ordinary computer plus a high resolution soundcard.

Some sound sample editing tool may have a display mode which resembles Page D, but I have not one. A person who understands waveform math, of course, could program very realistic page D type visualizations in math programs (Matlab, Wolfram) or even as a plotted a spreadsheet in programs like Excel.

Comment: Thank you! The article you gave me is very useful. I have also considered implementing it through this method, but I feel maybe modifying each line would be too much work. If I want to make an dynamic poster, it will be even more difficult.

Comment: Drawing the curves or at least a few of them to blend the rest is actually easy if one needs only a static image and bothers to practice a while. And fine twists can be made with effects as I did with Wrinkle. Animation is another thing, some algorithmic generation is needed.